# How to get Siri to read result from the web

Tags: iphone, siri

Siri is frustrating. I can ask her a question like "what causes brain freeze" (as one does), and she'll say "I found this on the web". But if I then ask her to "speak screen" or "read page", or even "read it to me", she has no idea what I'm talking about and tells me there's nothing to read.

Folk, I understand how to get my phone to read a page. What I don't understand is how *completely hands-free* you can ask Siri a question and get her to read the web page of the result she just found you.

Alexa can do it. Google can do it. What's wrong with Siri?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you can use Siri to speak screen when the results are open in Safari, or when it shows specific excerpt from Wikipedia or WolframAlpha etc. for say, word meanings or definitions.

For the results in the overlay, it seems not possible to me.

I search using iPhone's spotlight and then use "search the web" at the bottom in case I need more results.

You can look into setting up a automation for opening safari and reading it out aloud.

Comment: That's been my experience as well. Is there a voice command to open the search result from the overlay into Safari?

Comment: I dont think so. see the edited answer for a workaround.

Comment: What if the phone is locked?

Answer (score -1):

I had similar problem but with turning on "Hey siri" I managed to get it to read SOME results even tho I was asking similar questions

Comment: This is more of a comment than an actual answer.  *How* did you manage to get it to read web results?

Comment: I said "with turning on "Hey siri I managed to get it to read SOME results" --> by turning on "Hey Siri" (how)

Answer (score -2):

Step one install Alexa on your phone from the Apple App Store.

Step two use Siri to launch Alexa using the command. "Hey Siri, launch Alexa."

Step three use the Alexa trigger word "Alexa", followed by the question you seek to have answered.

Comment: The question asked "How to get **Siri**..." not another virtual assistant.

Comment: This is just a rant in disguise.  I'm voting as VLQ to put in the queue for deletion.